# Google api серверная авторизация

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar

Добрый день. Уже какой день бьюсь с google api.
Подключил google-api-php-client, создал и подключил JWT(json-файл) для использования service-account доступа к API (без oauth2). Но, видать, где-то не досмотрел, так как доступа к данным календаря так и не получил. 
Вот что имеем:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
$credentials_file = 'calendar-91713b63060f.json';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("calendar");
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']);
$client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $optParams);
var_dump($results);
```

Код даже выполняется, но возвращает странные значения:

```
object(Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList)#67 (10) {
["collection_key":protected]=> string(5) "items" 
["etag"]=> string(18) ""p32sf76fmi6css0g"" 
["itemsType":protected]=> string(41) "Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry" 
["itemsDataType":protected]=> string(5) "array" 
["kind"]=> string(21) "calendar#calendarList" 
["nextPageToken"]=> NULL 
["nextSyncToken"]=> string(84) "CLjzmfaRmc4CEjRjYWxlbmRhckBtYWNyby1tZW5kZXItMTM3ODIzLmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29t" 
["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } 
["modelData":protected]=> array(1) { 
//В этом поле не должно быть пустого массива..
    ["items"]=> array(0) { } } 
["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

Если кто сталкивался с Google Calendar API и Service account буду рад услышать совет))

Answer (score 1):

А что, если дополнить и выполнить код прямо из [документации](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php)? Что вы на выходе вообще хотите получить?

```
if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
  print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
  print "Upcoming events:\n";
  foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    if (empty($start)) {
      $start = $event->start->date;
    }
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
  }
}
```

Comment: На выходе я должен получить список календарей (точнее объект, в котором items хранит массив календарей). Проблема в том, что я получаю общую информацию, как будто я не авторизовался.